# Slack change theme from bot post

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a bot with the following code:

```
bot.on('message', function (data) {
    // all ingoing events https://api.slack.com/rtm
    console.log(data);
    if (data.content.includes('new')) {
        bot.postMessageToUser(data.subtitle, '#282828 ,#565656 ,#2AFC86 ,#282828 ,#434745 ,#FFFFFF ,#2AFC8e ,#DB6668 ');
    } else {
        bot.postMessageToUser(data.subtitle, 'I don\'t understand :scream_cat:\nPlease type "new" for a new color scheme.');
    }
});
```

When I post the color scheme, it looks like this:
[image]

However, when the bot posts the exact same thing it looks like this:
[image]

The way when I post it is the desired result. Any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `{as_user: true}` as a search parameters argument:

```
bot.on('message', function (data) {
    // all ingoing events https://api.slack.com/rtm
    console.log(data);
    if (data.content.includes('new')) {
        bot.postMessageToUser(data.subtitle, '#282828 ,#565656 ,#2AFC86 ,#282828 ,#434745 ,#FFFFFF ,#2AFC8e ,#DB6668 ', {as_user: true});
    } else {
        bot.postMessageToUser(data.subtitle, 'I don\'t understand :scream_cat:\nPlease type "new" for a new color scheme.', {as_user: true});
    }
});
```